# JSF composite attribute for defining a value

Tags: java, jsf, attributes, composite

Simple question I hope..I have my java class where a value is set to 3:

```
private static final Integer MAX_LANGUAGES = 3;
```

Could you give me an example how to make a composite attribute that will specify the maximum number of languages a user can select. It is now stored in the class but I would like it to be more flexible, because the class shouldnt depend on that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your talking about [`composite components`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html)?

If so, you can use the [`composite:attribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) tag to add an attribute to your component.

E.g:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="maxLanguages"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputFormat value="Maximum languages = {0}">
           <f:param value="#{cc.attrs.maxLanguages}"/>
    </h:outputFormat>
</composite:implementation>
```

You can also attach a real java model to it with the `componentType` attribute of `composite:interface` and access it properties with `cc.propertyName`

Comment: Yes,composite components. If I do it like that the maxLanguages is a null value of course. How can I now pass a value of 3 in it?

Comment: Like you would pass an attribute to any other component: `<n:yourComponent maxLanguages="5"/>`. Notice that there was a small error in the above snippet: Its `cc.attrs.maxLanguages` not ``cc.attr.maxLanguages``

Comment: Yeah. I've seen it. Thanks :)